# How to find resource in relative path in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My app structure is like:

```
index.html
main.ts
app
 |--main.component.html
 |--main.component.ts
 |--app.module.ts
 |--note.png
... etc
```

I want to use the note.png in main.component.html which is under the same folder.
I tried `<img src="note.png"/>` and `<img src="./note.png"/>`, but the picture is not shown.
The browser goes to `/note.png` to search for the picture.

Is there any good way to locate the resource using relative path?
I cannot use  because I may have many pages under different folders, their base href are different.

Comment: Angular is different from the normal html structure. In normal html, if we visit main.component.html, the url will be like /app/main.component.html. So if we use relative path in the html, it will goes to /app/note.png.   But in Angular, the url is /index.html,  but actually the page of main.component.html will be shown. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: you should ng-src

Comment: Let me know does my answer solve your problem or not?

Comment: Thanks very much for replying.  Is there ng-src in Angular? I am not using AngularJS. Even if I may use ng-src, what about those in style, like: `style="background-image: url(note.png); "`

Comment: So why are you add angular tag in your post

Comment: Angular is the next version of AngularJS.  From the version of 2, it is renamed to Angular. I am using Angular 5. This is the home page:https://angular.io

Comment: I tried ng-src, I am afraid it is removed from Angular

Comment: I believe you need to save it in an "Assets" folder at the root level of your app. eg: "your-application\src\assets\note.png"

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is the only way I can think of, but I don't like it. If I put all the images in Assets folder, it might be difficult to maintain. Because I may have many pages, each page have some different images. It will be a mess if I put them togethor

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Angular CLI, you can put your assets in any folders that you want. You just need to then add those folders to your .angular-cli.json file here:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

So if you wanted some of your images in an img folder, you'd modify it like this:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "img",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I want to put my images in the same folder with ts and html who use the image.  I don't want to create a asserts folder to store all the pictures of all the pages

Comment: I believe you can configure webpack to get assets from anywhere, but it's horrible. Just use assets and organize it correctly. 1 folder per component for example.